# Changing Inception-v4 architecture to do Multi-label classification in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I am working on image tagging and annotation problem, simply an image may contain multiple objects. I want to train inception-v4 for multi-label classification. My training data will be an image and a vector of length equals the number of classes and has 1 in each index if the object exists in the image. For example, If I have four classes (Person, car, tree, buildings). If an image contains a person and car. Then my vector will be (1, 1, 0, 0).

What changes do I need to make to train inception-v4 for the tagging and annotation problem?

Do I only need to change the input format and change the loss function from softmax to sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits in the inception-v4 architecture?

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v4.py

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and let us know how it worked? :)

Comment: how do you construct your label vector? If you used default slim standard, each image should have one-hot vector style label.

Comment: this is using inception-v3: https://github.com/BartyzalRadek/Multi-label-Inception-net

Answer (score -2):

If you'd like to retrain a model to output different labels, check out the `image_retraining` example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

In that example, we retrain the standard inception v3 model to recognize flowers instead of the standard ImageNet categories.

Comment: This is not multi label classification